# Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss Python

Tags: python

What do I write in print to make this thing display seconds in hh:mm:ss format? Sorry if Im saying some BS since I'm really new to coding

```
x = int(input())
s = x
m = x//60
h = x//3600
print(
```

Comment: Have a look at `f-strings`

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input())
s = x % 60
m = (x//60) % 60
h = x//3600
print( "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (h,m,s) )
```

Depending on what you're doing, it might be better to use the `datetime` module for this.

Comment: Saving some work (at least in theory), you could do `s = int(input())`, `m, s = divmod(s, 60)`, `h, m = divmod(m, 60)`. That said, the duplicate has even more direct solutions.